# How can I determine that the requester is my web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication

I have a web app where I don't want someone else to call my endpoints and use the provided JSON data outside my website. Is there something unique to my web app (or create something that no one can see on the devtools) that I can send via the request headers? and does CORS help here since the server and the app lives on the same project

```js
fetch(url,{
  method : 'GET',
  hedears : {
    // something unique for my website
  }
})
```

Comment: Ask for a username and password?

Comment: @MatJ the web app doesn't have authentication system ( no users ) just a simple web app

Comment: That's not trivial. The easiest way is to set an static id in yor web app and your server validates this id.

Comment: @user121548789, Add one then, Its the solution to your problem.

Comment: I think you should use some authentication like a bearer token to access the web api from ui.

Comment: the user can simply make his own token and get access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

- Create a unique session ID (on the *server*) that you send with the main page of the app and then require for all calls related to the app.
- Use SSL to ensure that that unique session ID isn't stolen from the HTTP traffic in-transit.
- Rate-limit responses even with a valid session ID (for instance, only X requests from IP Y within Z time), since a malicious actor can use a browser-like process to connect to your app and mine it through that session.
- *(Optionally)* You can lock it down to the original requesting IP (but beware that sometimes, clients change IP — for instance, on a fast-moving train).

Various authentication systems do the above for you.

Other than what you can serve up in that main page and the require on subsequent requests, there's nothing you can do to prevent bad actors querying your endpoints via non-browser processes.

But if your users aren't authenticated (you've said there's no login), note that a sufficiently-motivated malicious attacker will be able to use a botnet to circumvent all of the above, looking like normal users to you. If you need to mitigate that (you can't *prevent* it), you'll need to have the concept of users that sign up, have their signup verified (anywhere from just replying to a link in an email — easily defeated by a bad actor — or requiring something a human at your end has to verify), and have them log in. And, again, even *that* is mitigation, raising the bar further, not prevention.

> and is CORS helpful here?

No, quite the opposite. But the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) is useful here, meaning you don't have to worry about other websites using your website's data *directly* in the browser via ajax. ([CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) is something you'd use to *allow* them to do that.)

Comment: Create a unique session ID that you send with the main page of the app" ...is creating a unique ID on the frontend is a good idea since all the code is available via the browser ?

Comment: @user121548789 - You wouldn't create it on the front-end, you'd create it on the server and serve it with the main app's HTML. That's why I said "send it with the main page."

Comment: then someone can just call the endpoint and make his own token right

Comment: @user121548789 - Yes, see the bullet about rate-limiting, and the paragraph on botnets.

Comment: @user121548789 - I've expanded that botnet paragraph a bit to try to make it more helpful.

Comment: Yeah sound great i might go with that ... thanks for the help